# Memory footprint of the pass parameter by pointer and pass parameter by the reference

Tags: c++, memory-management

Pass by pointer:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int tmp;

    tmp = *b;
    *b = *a;
    *a = tmp;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6; 
    printf("%d and &d", a, b);
    swap(&a, &b);
    printf("%d and &d", a, b);
}
```

How the memory footprint of these two functions is different from the one when using pass by reference?

Pass by reference:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int tmp;

    tmp = b;
    b = a;
    a = tmp;
}

int main()
{ 
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6; 
    printf("%d and &d", a, b);
    swap(a, b);
    printf("%d and &d", a, b);
}
```

Comment: There are no references in C. Please to not add unrelated language tags.

Comment: @tkausl now should work.

Comment: You can't make a judgement by looking at the code. You need to look at the generated assembly and that of course varies.

Comment: `printf("%d and &d", a, b);` ==> `printf("%d and %d", a, b);`

Comment: Please only copy&paste code that actually compiles. That avoids errors during retyping from memory.

Comment: When you fix the syntax errors, you'll get the same from most compilers. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/y5ery6

Comment: To say roughly, reference can be considered as a synonym to variable however pointer contains an address of this variable. Actually a reference is more convinient for using than pointers in some cases and please, if you write on ANSI C, write on it :) When you write on C++ avoid functions that are used in C and better to use ```std``` functions

Comment: Please post the measurement that indicates a memory footprint difference.